# Blackberry JDE and Sqlite timestamp

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, jde

I am trying to store a date from a DateField into an sqlite database, but can't figure out what format to store/retrieve it in to preserve the value.  I have been trying with the sqlite datatype as 'timestamp' and using 'long' in the application.  When I retrieve the date though, it goes to 1970 instead of 2010-ish.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else was having a problem, this approach does work.  Use timestamp in the database and long in your app.  My problem was I was reading in the value into an int by accident and it was wrapping around.  Reading into a long will make it work.